# Determine the best chunk size in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I’m working on a spring boot project which uses spring batch. I’ve got so many questions on my mind regarding spring batch, here they are :

1. Is there any convention of how to determine the best chunk size?
2. What’s affected by the chunk size in term of performance? For example, the chunk size affected RAM usage or else.

I’ll really appreciate any answers/opinions because I’ve searched everywhere for the answers of those questions and still I haven’t found any good answers.

Comment: It's surely RAM related, if you have chunks of 500 items you safe more to RAM then with chunk sizes of 5 items. Apart from that, asking for opinions is off-topic for SO, and to answer your question on how to determine the best chunk size we would need to know your program and data in complete. Try what works best for your program and machine, that's the only way to find out. I'm sure one could calculate it too though